# MySQL (or Mariadb) Expression with DATEDIFF and DATETIME() OR NOW()

Tags: mysql, mariadb

What is wrong here?

```
CREATE TABLE `actionAngebot` (
    `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `expiryDat` SMALLINT DEFAULT UNSIGNED AS (DATEDIFF(`createdAt`, DATETIME())) STORED
)
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '() )) STORED ) ENGINE=MyISAM' at line 3 *

please do not propose me this :

```
CREATE TABLE `promos` (
    `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `createdTil` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `expiryDateOfReward` SMALLINT(10) AS ((to_days(`createdAt`) - to_days(`createdTil`))) VIRTUAL
)
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

I want to make it with 2 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your current query is that `DATETIME` is a data type, not a function, so you can't call it as one. `DATETIME` is not valid in that position either, you would need to use `NOW()` or `CURDATE()` dependent on whether you wanted a difference to the date and time or just date.

**But**

You can't use expressions for generated columns which include functions based on system date and time, so you cannot do what you want (see the [manual](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/generated-columns/#expression-support)). You could consider creating a view instead:

```
CREATE VIEW aabot AS
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(`createdAt`, NOW()) AS expiryDat
FROM actionAngebot
```

Comment: Your view would give me the time difference at the moment of the query ? or at the moment of the updated table ?

Comment: @HenryStack it would give you the time difference at the moment of the query. If you want it at the moment the table gets updated then you really have no choice other than the third column you mention in your question.

Comment: t0x  &nbsp;  &nbsp;